# Applying jquery modification to meteor site

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am using a free template from [HTML5up](http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/lens/) which has a `main.js` and `util.js` files. These contain code that control the look and feel of the sight. I have moved these files to the the `client/lib` folder as recommended.

The template uses `jquery`, `poptrox` plugin to `jquery` and `skel` for the layout. It resizes images and crops them to fit to the square div box.

The problem is that if I insert the images manually in the HTML everything works well.

```
<div id="main">
    <article class="thumb">
        <a href="images/0.JPG" class="image">
            <img src="images/0.JPG" alt="" />
        </a>
    </article>              
</div>
```

but if I use a template and let meteor load the image data:

```
<template name="ImageT">
   {{#each imageUrl}}
      <article class="thumb">
         <a href="images/{{image}}" class="image">
         <img src="images/{{image}}" alt="" /></a>
      </article>
    {{/each}} 
</template>
```

The image loads up but the scaling and resizing does not happen. From what I can see, the `poptrox` extension does not load.

This is the jquery code in the template that I think is responsible for this:

```
// Main.
var $main = $('#main');

// Thumbs.
$main.children('.thumb').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
    $image = $this.find('.image'), $image_img = $image.children('img'),
                        x;

    // No image? Bail.
    if ($image.length == 0)
        return;

    // Image.
    // This sets the background of the "image" <span> to the image pointed to by its child
    // <img> (which is then hidden). Gives us way more flexibility.

    // Set background.
    $image.css('background-image', 'url(' + $image_img.attr('src') + ')');

    // Set background position.
    if (x = $image_img.data('position'))
        $image.css('background-position', x);

    // Hide original img.
    $image_img.hide();

});
```

### EDIT

On suggestion from Answer#1 I moved the relevant code to `Template.ImageT.onRendered()`

```
i=0
Template.ImageT.onRendered(
  function(){

     $main = $('#main');
     $main.children('.thumb').each(function(){

       var  $this = $(this),
         $image = $this.find('.image'), $image_img = $image.children('img'),
         x;

       // No image? Bail.
         if ($image.length == 0)
           return;

       // Image.
       // Set background.
           $image.css('background-image', 'url(' + $image_img.attr('src') + ')');

         // Set background position.
           if (x = $image_img.data('position'))
             $image.css('background-position', x);

         // Hide original img.
           $image_img.hide();

       console.log("This function ran: "+i)
       i=i+1;
     });



    console.log("This ran");
  });
```

This runs only once (corresponding to the initial element) and not on the meteor rendered templates.

If I run this with 2 elements in HTML:

```
 Ran on 0 index.js:38 
 Ran on 1 index.js:44
```

But none of the meteor template inserted elements render.

### Edit 2

When I go to another page and "back" into the home page, the code works as expected.

Comment: Note: If you use the .onRendered as suggested (per image) 'this' inside the '.onRendered' will be the current article element. Therefore you should be able to put all the code inside the '.thumb .each' function straight into the .onRendered function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now have only one template, this one is rendered once (on page load).

You want to run the initialisation of the jQuery functions after Meteor renders the HTML for each image. To do this you can call a subtemplate in the imageT template {{each}}.

```
<template name="ImageT">
   {{#each imageUrl}}
      {{> image}}
    {{/each}} 
</template>

<template name="image">
    <article class="thumb">
      <a href="images/{{image}}" class="image">
      <img src="images/{{image}}" alt="" /></a>
    </article>
</template>
```

Then the JS

```
Template.Image.onRendered = function() {
    //Put code to run every time an image is rendered below
});
```

Also see the Meteor docs [Template.myTemplate.onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-onRendered)

Comment: So of what I understand - that code is in this sort of a structure: (function($) {})(jquery)

I do not fully understand this construct. Should I copy this into the onRendered?

Comment: I just browsed the code. It seems the main.js code creates a global variable called "main". If you put main.init(); into the onRendered I think it should work.

Comment: This is assuming you are using the "lens" template from html5up. That is the one you referenced in your link.

Comment: This is the code that I managed to take out and put together: http://pastebin.com/TZ2Fveqy

I still have the same problem, where only the first element reacts to this code.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think the culprit is that the ImageT onRendered was only triggered once. When using a subtemplate and attaching the onRendered to that one you ensure that the code runs after every image that renders.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!