# Meteor events not firing

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am making a card game. Players take turn. The player can not throw any card, but is limited by the previous card thrown. If previous player throws 7 of clubs, current player can only throw clubs. (more complicated than this, but...)

I solved this by having two css classes, cardRegular and cardThrowable where cardThrowable moves the card up onmousehover, indicating to the user that the card can be thrown.

I have defined these events:

```
Template.card.events({
    "click .cardThrowable": function () {
        console.log("click .cardThrowable " + this);
    },
    "click .cardRegular": function () {
        console.log("click .cardRegular " + this);
    }
});
```

When I open the page, both events work just fine in both browsers (for two player), however, once one player throws his card I have a problem.

The second players cards are properly updated and only allowed cards have the cardThrowable class, but neither event is fired.

If I simply refresh the page, then the events are properly fired, but then the other user has the same issue. Until he refreshes the page...

I am totally lost as to what may be causing this bug.

EDIT:
Cards template

```
<template name="cards">
    <div class="cardsDIV">
        {{#each playerCards}}
            {{> card}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="card">
    {{{card this}}}
</template>
```

...

```
Template.card.helpers({
    card: function () {
        return '<img src="' + cardImage(this.cardName) +
            '" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:' + this.left + 'px" class="' + this.css + '" />';
    }
});
```

Comment: This can probably be solved by putting the actual card elements in a subtemplate and attaching the events to that template. You would have to show me some of your templating to confirm this though.

Comment: Probably similar situation to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35412089/4699406

Comment: Are you using publish and subscribe ?

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma: Actually, I am using a subtemplate for the card elements and attaching the event to that template :(

Comment: @StefanL19: Yes of course, I am using publish/subscribe.

Comment: Did you try putting the img tag into the template in stead of the helper? Since the event handler can use the context of the template you don't even need to have two event handlers but can use one. I will post a code example in a minute

Comment: Could you post the code from publish and subscribe methods?

Comment: Usually, when the everything works "after refresh" the problem is in the publication.

Comment: the problem is that events are attached to the img element at creation, but you replace the img tag with another at run time when you update the card, essentially clearing the event handlers that are attached on creation of the template. This is why it works when you refresh and then doesn't. The solution below only updates the necessary css without updating the img element, so it keeps the events handlers untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the event handlers are not attached because the way you are adding the cards.

I don't quite understand how you are getting the values for css and left but I assume by the way you use them that they are values in the card document

Try something like this HTML:

```
<template name="card">
  <img class="{{this.css}} js-playCard" src="{{this.cardName}}" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:{{this.left}}px" />
</template>
```

And this JS:

```
Template.card.events({
  'click .js-playCard'(event, instance) {
    console.log("clicked " + this.css);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am calculating the "left" and "css" values on the fly because these depend on the user sorting and previously thrown cards...

Comment: Maybe you can try the pattern I suggest without those for now. Just to see if the events do fire with this.

Comment: Great. Have fun programming your app!